# Is there an equivalent of Python Tutor for R?

Tags: programming, debugging, r

Is there a tool like [Python Tutor](https://pythontutor.com/) that help beginners by showing code execution step by step?.

I know that you can use the RStudio's debugger, be I will be using it in a course where the students don't know anything about programming.